# 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

Here is what I have:

```
var listAddresses = GetAddresses().ToList();
return Json(new JsonResult { Data = new SelectList(listAddresses, "Name", "Id") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

But I get the error 'System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject' does not contain a property with the name 'Name'.

listAddresses is consisted of 10 items. When I debug, when I watch each one of them, I go to Dynamic View and there is Name and Id. How to recolve this?

Comment: I believe you need to cast to the appropriate object type and all should work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var listAddresses = GetAddresses().ToList();
var data = new 
{ 
    Data = new SelectList(listAddresses, "Name", "Id") 
};
return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

`Json(...)` is a `JsonResult`, you don't need both.

Answer (score 0):

try like this-->

```
var listAddresses = GetAddresses().ToList(); 
        List<ListItem> addressList = new List<ListItem>();
        foreach (IAddress address in listAddresses )
            {
                ListItem items = new ListItem();
                items.Text = address.Name;
                items.Value = address.ID;
                addressList .Add(items);


            }
        }
    return Json(new JsonResult { Data = new SelectList(addressList, "Value", "Text") }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use dynamic features of C# without using the `dynamic` keyword.  So:

```
var listAddreses = GetAddresses().ToList();
```

leaves you with a `List<ExpandoObject>` which really truly does not have any of the properties you mentioned.  *However* if you say:

```
List<dynamic> listAddresses = GetAddresses().ToList();
```

It should work.